# How do I get Windows Server 2003 IIS to play nice with SSL in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, ssl

I'm trying to run Apache with SSL on a Windows 2003 server and when I enabled the configuration and restart Apache I get an error:

> (OS 10048) Only one usage of each
>   socket address (protocol/network
>   address/port) is normally permitted. 
>   : make_sock: could not bind to address
>   0.0.0.0:443 no listening sockets available, shutting down

It appears I do have a service HTTP SSL running on Windows, and shutting it down means I can't run IIS. How do I stop HTTP SSL as a Windows service, keep IIS running, and have Apache handle SSL?

Comment: Does stopping IIS actually allow apache to run?  How do you know IIS is the service using the port?  You might want to fire up tcpview (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) and verify that it is actually IIS that is using port 443 and not something else.

Comment: you nailed it Zoredache, I had a random (HP Power Backup) application running on port 443.. thanks for the note! If you make an answer of it, I'd gladly vote it up and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You could change IIS to listen on an [alternate port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605) for SSL.  Or if the system has multiple IP addresses, then you should be able to bind IIS to one, and Apache to another.

Comment: I can not find on any of the "Web Sites" in IIS that are actually bound to use port 443 for SSL.